# CQRS multi threaded query processing

Tags: cqrs

We are building our application based on CQRS. The Command and Query share the same table for most information, but for some heavily read data, we are planning to have a separate query table to avoid multiple joins. Command part will update its data then publish an event, query part will listen to these events and update its own data "eventually". Now the problem/question is that Command part will execute in a multi-threaded environment, i.e. multiple users will work on different data in parallel. But the Query part has to process these events in a sequential way because the order of events is important, so it cannot be multi-threaded, you may use different threads for different type of events but only one thread can process a single type of event. In that case how well this architecture scale? or am I missing something?

Answer (score 5):

> We are building our application based on CQRS. The Command and Query share the same table for most information, but for some heavily read data, we are planning to have a separate query table to avoid multiple joins.

So this architecture is not CQRS, because the separation is not complete. In order to be CQRS you need to have separate models and even databases/tables/collections.

> But the Query part has to process these events in a sequential way because the order of events is important, so it cannot be multi-threaded

Let's talk a little about what we could have.

There are two possibilities regarding the ordering of events:

1. The Read-model expects the events to be in total order; this means that the Read-model's code wants to process the events in the order they where generated. This implies that the events need to have some sort of global sequence number (an integer or a timestamp, like MongoDB's [Timestamp](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/#timestamps) which are unique per instance).

   - pros: simpler Read-model code
   - cons: limiting scaling of the Write-model, as the global ordering needs some strong-ish synchronization between writers
2. The Read-model does not expect the events to be in a total order, ordering in a single Stream would suffice; a Stream is the collection of events, having multiple types, generated by a single Entity (like the Aggregate in DDD), that are ordered. That is, the events in a Stream are always in the correct order.

   - pros: very good scalability on the Write side of the architecture, no global synchronization between writers (machines, nodes)
   - cons: complex Read-model code as it must reorder or wait for events until it updates its visible data

In neither of these cases, the Read-model consumes only events of a single type. A Read-model may consume many types of events, and in general they do. Imagine a List-of-active-users Read-model: it needs the `UserCreated`, `UserActivated` and `UserDeleted` event types, in a fictional use-case.

> ...because the order of events is important, so it cannot be multi-threaded...

It can be multi-threaded/scaled if you find a dimension by which you can *cut*. If the event types are generated by a single Entity type, then you can split the Read-model workers by the Entity ID, by using a hash of the ID for example; all workers could update the Read-model's database without stepping on each others feet, because each one updates a different Entity.

In our fictional use-case, you could split by UserId. So, each Read-model worker gets a range of ID-is that it should process. For example, the worker 1 gets to process the IDs from 1 to 100, the second worker gets to process the IDs from 101 to 200 and so on. When a Read-model worker gets an event (by fetching, polling, pub/sub, whatever mean), it extract the UserId from it (i.e. `event.getUserId()`) and if it does not match its assigned range, it just ignores it.

In a more complex case, when you need events from different Entity types, you can still scale. Just like in the above case, you just need to find a dimension by which to cut. But in this case, there will be event types that do not have that dimension. *Those events will be processed by all the workers, that is, they are not ignored*.

In our fictional case, when an event comes from the `UserAggregate`, you split by `UserId`, but when the event comes from `RoleAggregate` (yes, you guessed, this is a Authentication and Authorization bounded context), it does not have a `UserId` property, so it is processed by the Read-model, it is not rejected.

So, it all reduces to choosing a dimension. In general, the dimension is the main Entity's ID, as many Read-models are in fact lists of Entities, with denormalized data attached to them. For example, our fictional `List-of-active-users Read-model` is a list of users that where not deactivated and that have also the Roles that are associated with them.

These patterns could be applied to some extent to Sagas/Process managers also.